# InAppBrowser not loading pdf Phone gap 2.7.0

Tags: android, pdf, cordova

I am having issue with InAppBrowser on Android,it is not loading/displaying pdf file.

```
     var ref = window.open('http://178.239.16.28/fzs/sites/default/files/dokumenti-vijesti/sample.pdf', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

I tried with _system,it is downloading the file.But I want it as just display without download. I found the same questions in Stackoverflow but didnt find the exact answer as per my requirement.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Andoid InAppBrowser has no power to open Pdf. But ios has.. If you need to open pdf please try with google Doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This..

```
    var ref = window.open("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://178.239.16.28/fzs/sites/default/files/dokumenti-vijesti/sample.pdf", '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

Becuse Andoid Webkit has not power to Directly open pdf as IOS.. So open with google Doc.

Comment: Yeah .. I tried with fileOpener, Childbrowser plugins but not displaying. finally I used google docs to display it . Everyone saying  it is working fine with Cordova version 3.0 but I didnt tested it yet.

Comment: yup dear. I have tryied also with 3.0.0 is work fine.. I have tryied to make my custome pdfview i have done perfectly my job but problem is i have use one lib so that lib attach one water markin there so i can't work more then. But Google Doc is perfect solution. Well Nice name GiGi